# How can I use an endpoint policy to restrict the traffic going from a internal network to access a private APIs?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-rest-api

I've read from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-vpc-endpoint-policies.html

> You can use an endpoint policy to restrict the traffic going from your internal network to access your private APIs.

What exactly would this policy look like?

I want to only allow traffic to the endpoint from Direct Connect only.

Comment: Similar to an resource policy that set on API Gateway. Check out the examples in the same doc. Probably add some details in your question on what kind of restriction would you like to perform like IAM user, or access to a specific API etc.

Comment: I want to allow on prem only via dx

Comment: Instead of using policies on VPC endpoint to restrict traffic from on-prem, you could use security groups on the VPC endpoint to whitelist the on-prem IP range from where requests are made. On API Gateway, whitelist the VPC endpoint in the resource policy then.

Comment: How can I whitelist the VPC Endpoint security group for just the Direct Connect traffic? If you could help me determine how exactly to whitelist a single DX connection in security group, Ill gladly accept as answer.

Comment: Or whitelist in the VPC Endpoint policy. Either way, I just want a single entry for the direct connect traffic.